# Create prototype for data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering if it was possible to create a prototype for a specific data attribute. For example:

- JS creates an image element (or any type of element) with the data attribute `data-fruit` and sets it to `banana`

or

- JS adds the attribute `data-fruit` with value `pineapple` to an element

or

- An element with `data-fruit` with any value is simply loaded onto the page

When this attribute is found in the HTML document, I want an ajax request to be made telling my server that there is now an element with a `data-fruit` attribute containing value `[value_of_the_fruit]`

Comment: Sure, it's possible, but seems overly complicated, why not just do an ajax request when you add that data attribute etc. instead.

Comment: I awith with @adeneo. Anyway, if you like these abstraction take a look at React (framework for building UI) that supports JSX (JS + XML),

Comment: @adeneo The problem is that the element is created with someone else's JS, and I can't make any sense of his JS. I do know that his JS creates a data-attribute and assigns  it a specific value depending on certain circumstances. I want to alert my server of those circumstances

Comment: Is there atleast some documentation on how to do it?

Comment: If someone elses code is adding attributes, the only thing I can think of would be to look at Mutation Observers, but that's generally not a very good idea.

Comment: will that work for elements that are created on the fly? I looked into [mozilla's documentation][1], and I was wondering if the target had to be a pre-existing element or could the mutationobserver work on just a prototype?
[1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver